# POST method from form returns null

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to use post with express and bodyparser to insert data into MYSQL from a form in a ejs file. It keeps returning null, so it seems that my data is not parsed from the form to my backend.
Could you please help?

Here is my server.js

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '100mb', extended: false }));
dotenv.config();


// Set the default views directory to html folder
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'html'));

// Set the folder for css & java scripts
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'css')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));

// Set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

my index.js

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
const formData = { username : req.body.username, account : req.body.account, email : req.body.email, 
    address : req.body.address, start_date : req.body.start_date, picture : req.body.picture, 
    request : req.body.request };
const sqlPut = "INSERT INTO dbTable ?";
const query = dbconn.conn.query(sqlPut, formData, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.redirect('/about')
})
```

})

Here is my ejs file with the form.

```
<div class="container" >  
<form id="contact" action="/save" method="post">
  <h3>New scholar form</h3>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="username" id="username" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="account" id="account" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="email" id="email" type="email" tabindex="3" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="bnc_address" id="bnc_address" type="text" tabindex="4" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    Scholar start date <input placeholder="start_date" type="date" tabindex="4" required> 
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="picture" id="picture" type="text" tabindex="4" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea placeholder="Scholar request..." id="request" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I can retrieve data from the database and post it just fine. I just haven't figured this one out.
I haven't posted here in a while, so bear with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported body-parser without using it. After I removed the import it started working.

Removed this, even though it was not used, it started working after:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '100mb', extended: true }));
```

Parses the text as URL encoded data(which is how browsers tend to send form data from regular forms set to POST) and exposes the resulting object (containing the keys and values) on req.body.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. It does still not work. My code still tries to insert null into the database.